# GeoTIFF - multiple tiles with different georeferencing

Tags: geotiff-tiff

Can I have GeoTIFF file with multiple tiles where each tile has different bounds? The projection is the same for all tiles.

If it is possible, how can I create such file?

I have tried:

When I create tiled tif with:  `gdalbuildvrt out.vrt 0_0.tif 2_2.tif` and `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" out.vrt mosaic.tif` the resulting TIFF when listed with `gdalinfo` acts as a single gereferenced image. There are only one corner coordinates, but I would expect two sets, one for each tile. If I open this image in QGis, I get one large image with tiles but places where no tile is are "black". I expected that places with no tile will be "empty".

I have also tried `gdal_merge.py -o output.tif -of gtiff 0_0.tif 2_2.tif"`, but with the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "tile"?  Please elaborate.

Comment: From my understanding, single TIFF file can contain multiple images aka "tiles" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Tiles

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.  Interesting question, and I'm looking forward to an expert answer.

Comment: Tiled GeoTIFFs are very common. You can create such for example with gdal_translate by using creation option `-co tiled=yes`. Cloud Optimised Geotiffs are special sort of tiled tiffs. More information for example in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html and https://www.cogeo.org/.

Comment: And you can control the size of the tiles with `gdal_translate` using `-co BLOCKXSIZE=X` and `-co BLOCKYSIZE=Y` where X & Y are the desired width and height of your tiles in pixels.

Comment: I have edited the question by ading additional info from test

Comment: Tiled tiff files do not work as you suppose. Reading the TIFF specification may help. The tile in a tiff is a rectangular region of the image and it can be accessed effectively by TIFF programs. The idea is to read the image file directory, analyze the structure of the image, locate the tile, and find the byte offset to the location where the data for that tile exists. For example GDAL is doing that in the background. When it comes to black areas, if you set 0 to mean nodata then black areas area interpreted to mean missing data. Adding an alpha band might be better alternative.

Comment: Why don't you simply open the .vrt file with QGIS?